# Edit row on Edit button click in 'react-bootstrap-table-next'

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am trying to implement a table using 'react-bootstrap-table-next'. **I want the row to be editable only after the click of the 'edit' button.** Currently, with my code on click of the cell, the cell is changed into an editable cell.

Screenshot of what I want to achieve.

[image]

***My Code:***

```
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next'
import cellEditFactory from 'react-bootstrap-table2-editor';

 const buttonFormatter = (cell, row) => {
    console.log(cell,row)
    return <Button onClick={()=>{editTenantHandler(cell,row)}}><FaEdit/></Button>;
}

  const columns = [{
    dataField: 'tenantName',
    text: 'Tenant Name',
    headerStyle: {
      color: 'white'
    }
  }, {
    dataField: 'email',
    text: 'Email',
    headerStyle: {
      color: 'white'
    }
  }, {
      dataField: 'mobile',
      text: 'Mobile',
      headerStyle: {
        color: 'white'
      }
    },
    {
      dataField: 'actions',
      text: 'Actions',
      isDummyField: true,
      csvExport: false,
      formatter: buttonFormatter,
      headerStyle: {
        color: 'white'
      }
    }];

  <BootstrapTable 
     keyField='tenantName' 
     data={ props.tenants } 
     columns={ columns } 
     cellEdit={ cellEditFactory({mode: 'click'}) }/>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? Same use-case here but the feature is not yet implemented in the plugin: https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/issues/1194